# "Watch updates" module (Make/Integromat) doesnt work

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, make.com, integromat-apps

The "Watch updates" module doesnt work. I am trying only with this module to test it, but it doesnt work.

I make a bot with botfather, and use SendPulse and Make to create the flow of a chatbot. I think that the problem something more than only Make. I think of a problem with Telegram, but since I'm making the bot without too much technical knowledge (as you will see), I can't find the solution.

Do you know any solution? Thanks

When I deleted the webhook connection and recreated the scenario in Make (Integromat), it works, and after a while it stops working again. Does not read new incoming messages. I do not know what to do